# java.net.NoRouteToHostException: No route to host

Tags: java, hadoop, hive

I am trying to create a folder /tmp and /usr/local/hive/warehouse in HDFS for for installing HIVE, but it says:

```
Retrying connect to server: 0.0.0.0/0.0.0.0:9000. Already tried 0     time(s);retry policy is RetryUpToMaximumCountWithFixedSleep(maxRetries=10, sleepTime=1 SECONDS)
```

It tries to connect for 10 times and finally gives the exception:

```
mkdir: Call to 0.0.0.0/0.0.0.0:9000 failed on local exception: java.net.NoRouteToHostException: No route to host
```

Note: my hadoop location is

> /usr/local/hadoop

and my hive location is

> /usr/local/hive

What am I doing wrong? I have probably not properly congifured one of the Hadoop configuration files.Please help.

Comment: check your /etc/hosts entries first. then do ping/traceroute to understand whether you have appropiate routing defined or not.

Comment: it says there is no **hosts** folder inside /etc

Comment: */etc/hosts* is file not folder.  do *cat /etc/hosts*

Comment: I checked my /etc/hosts file, it looks like this:                                                                    **127.0.0.1 localhost localhost.localhostdomain localhost4 localhost4.localdomain4                                                                                                 ::1 localhost localhost.localhostdomain localhost6 localhost6.localdomain6                                                                                        192.168.138.133 hadoop-psdeudocluster**

Comment: when I ping the hadoop-pseudocluster, I get **Destination Host Unreachable**

Comment: you need to put entry of *hadoop-pseudocluster <IP>* in /etc/hosts file.

Comment: It is already present. I think the problem is something else.

Comment: i put the ip in /etc/hosts, also when i ping it, it is responding. So there is no problem in it